# What is the verb for dividing something into regions?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Imagine a piece of paper on which you can draw some "regions". What do you call this act?

These words can probably better tell you what I mean, but I know they don't exist in English:

- Regionize: I regionized the paper
- Enregion: I enregioned the paper
- Region itself as a verb(?): I regioned the paper

---

In reality, I am a programmer "enregioning" a skin. I would be happier if the verb had clear relation with "region", because that is the technical term I am using for those parts of the skin. That way, the "enregioner" would both have a meaningful name and one that makes users understand it is creating "regions"

Comment: I have a feeling there is a technical term for what you are referring to as 'regions' of a skin. Will post an answer if I recall it.

Comment: Not really appropriate for this site, so I'm not making it an answer, but if you're using this in names or docs inside a program (i.e. not for end user consumption), don't feel bound by normal English usage! Something that isn't a real word but will obviously convey the meaning you want like "regionify" is superior *in the programming context* to a circumlocution or stretched synonym. I'd even argue that "regionify" would be superior to an adequate term like "partition" if you're using region as a technical term, since "partition" is more general so it tells you less.

Comment: @Ben, yeah, regionify sounds good!

Comment: When on subject of verbs for dividing into regions, you may look into a very specific one: [Gerrymandering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb I would use is **regionalize.** This would not refer to a "paper" partitioning, but rather dividing a country on a map for the purposes of say, marketing.

Comment: '''Regionalize''' is the only real choice if you want to an obvious connection to "region". The definition is "to divide into regions". It has been around since at least the 1920s according to [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regionalize). It is usually used in the context of creating administrative/marketing regions, although there is no reason it could not be used in other contexts.

Comment: @KevinCathcart: That is exactly why it is my choice.

Answer (score 17):

You may use

> I **partitioned** the paper.

or

> I **divided** the paper (into segments, sections, regions, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Would you please check out my edit?

Comment: Your edit doesn't affect the answer. If the Roman empire can partition Spain, you can partition a skin :)

Comment: Another verb could be *to parcel*. Check out the definiton of [*parceler*](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/Parceller).

Comment: @slim, I am not arguing with _partition_, it is great. Let me explain a little more. I have two stages, calibration and "regioning" a lot of places I have `skinCalibrationBegin/End/Reload` and analogously, I have `skinRegioningBegin/End/Reload`. Writing `skinDividingIntoRegionsBegin` seems too long. Writing `skinPartioningBegin` is vague (it doesn't explicitly say the result of the operation are _regions_). I was hoping I could turn _region_ into a verb, but apparently it's not possible.

Comment: Another noun for the result of *dividing* is *division*. I would avoid *parcel* since although it is correct, it is ambiguous and most people would misunderstand it.

Comment: @Shahbaz you could decide that the results of the operation are *partitions*.

Comment: @Shahbaz: since this is for a program, not for text (an article or paper) you can name it whatever you want. Trying to pin down the exact semantics for a class or function name is commendable but in the end, the class/function will have more in it than is expressible in the name. 'DividingIntoRegions' comes close, modern IDE's have cutandpaste and possibly autosuggest.

Comment: Alternatively, subdivide.

Comment: @Shahbaz: `skinRegionDivisionBegin`/`End`.  A gerund isn't the only or best way to form a noun referring to a process.

Comment: @BenVoigt, `skinRegionDivisionBegin/End` is actually good!

Answer (score 10):

You could *partition* the item into *partitions*.

You could *segment* the item into *segments*.

You could *divide* the item into *divisions*.

You could *apportion* into *portions*.

Comment: You can *lot* the item into *lots*, or *slice* the item into *slices*. You can *sectionalize* the item into *sections*.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use **demarcate**, I think it's probably closer to what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In the context of computer graphics and modeling, terms like *[mesh generation](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/mesh/)*, *[mesh triangulation](http://www.rabidgeek.net/projects/other/mesh-triangulation/)* ,  *[triangulation](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Triangulation)*, and *[optimal triangulation](http://fano.ics.uci.edu/cites/Document/Mesh-generation-and-optimal-triangulation.html)* are frequently used, and *grid generation* occasionally.  If all the regions on your paper are triangles, *triangulation* would be a good choice.

Comment: Since triangulation has another meaning, I think it could be confusing to users.

Comment: The regions are of arbitrary shape and size, they might not even be continuous. They are defined by the user so non of "triangulation" or "generation" seem appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of the term "contour" or "contouring"

> contour : To make or shape the outline of; represent in contour.

**or**

> create / establish / designate **zone**

Comment: I would avoid "contour" in the poster's context, because in that "mathsy" context, its definition of "*A line joining points on a diagram at which some property has the same value*" would hold more often.

Comment: contour is vertical, region is horizontal!

Answer (score 0):

**Partition** or **demarcate** seem adequate, but if there is more to the resultant program-areas or divisions than mere topography, then **allocate** might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, ***sectionalize***

> -·ized·, -·iz·ing
>
> 1. to make sectional
> 2. to divide into sections, esp. geographical sections
>
> [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sectionalize)